# Change libcups to repository version

Tags: apt

I upgraded my libcups package to 1.6 in hopes to fix something but I just buggered things up more. So I want to reinstall it to the version on the repository (1.5.3 I think).

I've tried to do a reinstall using

```
~#: apt-get install --reinstall libcups2
```

but that tells me it cannot be downloaded so refuses to upgrade.

I can't just do:

```
~#: apt-get remove libcups2
~#: apt-get install libcups2
```

as that wants to remove 299 packages along with it. Totaling 668MB so I am hesitant as that will probably take 6 hours to download on my connection.

Comment: How did you upgrade libcups? If you have added another repository, make sure that you remove it first and run `apt-get update`. If you did it manually, try downloading the package manually and installing it via dpkg.

Comment: @January I did it manually

Comment: Hm, now that I think of it -- can you please post the error message from `apt-get install --reinstall libcups2`?

Comment: Also, try `apt-get install libcups2=1.5.3

Comment: @January "Reinstallation of libcups2 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded." I will try your command next, I need to get the exact version name though. It's something like 1.5.3_ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, this is too long for a comment. First, check the available versions:

```
apt-cache madison libcups2
```

In my system (10.04) it gives output like this:

```
  libcups2 | 1.4.3-1ubuntu1.9 | http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main Packages
  libcups2 | 1.4.3-1ubuntu1.9 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main Packages
  libcups2 |    1.4.3-1 | http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
      cups |    1.4.3-1 | http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Sources
      cups | 1.4.3-1ubuntu1.9 | http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main Sources
      cups | 1.4.3-1ubuntu1.9 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main Sources
```

If I want to install one particular version, I'd do

```
apt-get install --reinstall libcups2=1.4.3-1ubuntu1.9
```

Possibly, you might need the option `--purge` as well. (beware, this will wipe your slate clean, including any configuration files).

Comment: Yep this worked. I did `sudo apt-get install libcups2=1.5.3*` because I didn't know how to find the version name. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It worked pretty fine with : "sudo apt-get install libcups2=2.2.7-1ubuntu2" for me (discarding security upgrades, however)